# Setting BrowserFlag per user for Citrix

Tags: ms-word, registry, citrix

We have an app running in IE that requires Word documents to open in Word rather than IE. For customers still using Word 2003, we recommend they use the [BrowserFlags registry setting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059) to alter this setting for users.

The registry key is in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`.

A customer wants to deliver the app through a Citrix farm and is concerned that because the key is `LOCAL_MACHINE` this setting would then apply to all users of the Citrix image.

Is this concern correct? Is it possible to set BrowserFlags under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is a merged view on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes so simply set the value in the HKCU hive.

Comment: Not sure what the protocol is here, as I've passed the answer on to our customer who can confirm that it works for them. I've accepted as an answer and will update if needed.